# way to save multiple instances of different class in django view

Tags: django, django-views

I want to create un new instance of my class Project. At each new Project, I want to associate a ProductionAsset to the project. And I want to associate a Task to the ProductionAsset.

The Class **Asset** has a foreignKey to the **Project**
**ProductionAsset** inherites the class Asset ,i.e., **ProductionAsset(Asset)**
The Class **Task** has a foreignKey to the class **Asset**

This is my code :

```
def createProject (request):
    projectForm=ProjectForm(request.POST)
    if projectForm.is_valid():
        projectForm.save()
        project = Project.objects.get(name=projectForm.cleaned_data.get("name") )
        asset = ProductionAsset(project=project, name='Production_'+project.name)
        asset.save()
        general=TaskTemplate.objects.get(name='General')
        task = Task(type=general, asset=asset,prefix=project.name) 
        task.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/projects/')
     else :
        return render(request,'error.html',Context({'errors':projectForm.errors}))
```

I feel bad to save several instances in the same view, but I don't know how to do differently.
Anyone can tell me if my code is right or if it is the wrong way to do ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why would this be bad?

Comment: newbie intuition :D. But according your answer It is not !

Comment: Note that `.save()` can fail so it's good to keep that in mind when saving multiple items in sequence.